# Excel 2013 64 bit - VBA Userform - Add 28 days to date of textbox and display in another textbox

Tags: excel, vba, userform, date-arithmetic

In my Userform I have a textbox "ADD_Inc_DATE_TXT" which the user manually enters the date of the incident.

I have another textbox "TxT_SWIRL_DueDate" which should display the result of the adding of 28 days to the date entered in the "ADD_Inc_DATE_TXT" textbox or even just add 1 month to the date of the incident.

I have tried this in a module named "Mod_SWIRL_Due_Date":

```
Sub SWIRL_ExpiryDate()

    TxT_SWIRL_DueDate = CDate(ADD_Inc_DATE_TXT)

    ADD_Inc_DATE_TXT = DateAdd("m", 1, ADD_Inc_DATE_TXT)

End Sub
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything at all.

I would like the "TxT_SWIRL_DueDate" to display the expiry date when the "ADD_INC_Time_TXT" textbox is selected.

And in anticipation of the User amending the Incident Date, I'd like it to update the TxT_SWIRL_DueDate with the amended date.

---

**Further Information:**
I have included below all the code I have relating to dates. I have 4 Date Pickers/Popup Calendars ... and none of the dates come up in the dd/mm/yyyy format. (having some problem with putting the code in the 'code sample' )

```
    Private Sub Calendar1_Click()
     ADD_Inc_DATE_TXT.value = CalendarForm.GetDate
     If IsDate(ADD_Inc_DATE_TXT.Text) Then
     Me.LBL_Inc_Day_Type.Caption = Format(ADD_Inc_DATE_TXT.Text, "ddd")

    End If
     If IsDate(ADD_Inc_DATE_TXT.Text) Then
     Me.ADD_Inc_DATE_TXT.Text = Format(ADD_Inc_DATE_TXT.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy") 
    End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Calendar2_Click()
     TXT_AssetMgr_DATE = CalendarForm.GetDate
       If IsDate(ADD_Inc_DATE_TXT.Text) Then
        Me.TXT_AssetMgr_DATE.Text = Format(TXT_AssetMgr_DATE.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub Calendar3_Click()
     TXT_LastUserDATE = CalendarForm.GetDate
     If IsDate(ADD_Inc_DATE_TXT.Text) Then
     Me.TXT_LastUserDATE.Text = Format(TXT_LastUserDATE.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Calendar4_Click()
      ADD_Date_ServiceJobLogged_TXT = CalendarForm.GetDate
      If IsDate(ADD_Inc_DATE_TXT.Text) Then
      Me.ADD_Date_ServiceJobLogged_TXT.Text =  Format(ADD_Date_ServiceJobLogged_TXT.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy")
     End If
     End Sub
```

---

‘Under Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() I have the following date related code: 
 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

```
            Me.ADD_Date_Recorded_TXT.value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy") ‘ this works perfectly (correct format is returned)
            Me.ADD_Time_Recorded_TXT.Text = Format(Now(), "HH:mm")
```

‘***Note: my system date is dd/mm/yyyy and in the spreadsheet cells, the format is set to dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code in the form's code module (right click the text box, "View code"):

```
Private Sub ADD_Inc_DATE_TXT_AfterUpdate()
  TxT_SWIRL_DueDate.Value = Format(DateAdd("m", 1, CDate(ADD_Inc_DATE_TXT.Value)),"dd/mm/yyyy")
End Sub
```

I recommend useing the AfterUpdate event, as the Change event fires every time the value in the textbox gets changed - eg also while typing. This only fires when the user has finished typing, and moved to the next tiem on the form (clicks somewhere else).

Also consider using some form of date control instead of textbox control. There are quite a few out there, and depending on the Excel version you are using, you may only be able to use a select few of those.

Comment: Thank you very much for you rapid response.

Comment: Sorry comment timed out. Your code works perfectly when date is typed in, except for 1 small glitch, the date that comes up is in the US format, where as I'd like it to be in the dd/mm/yyyy.  Also, I failed to mention that the textbox is populated by a pop-up calendar, which doesn't work with your code. When I said that the user manually enters date, I meant via date picker (didn't realise it made a difference). Could you explain what you meant by 'other control than textbox'. I'm currently having date formatting problems with the date picker no matter what I have tried ...

Comment: OK, for the output format, change the formatting of the textbox (select textbox, properties, format, and type `"dd/mm/yyyy"` *with* quotation marks).

Comment: As for the other problem: The popup calendar must have an event that you can use. Is that a control? Then it must have a Change or Update event. Is that an external little program, that actually writes a value to a textbox? Then use the same process that updates the first textbox to update thte second one too. Does this make sense to you? :)

Comment: Wow... you're on tap LOL, thank you again. I have gone to the properties of the textbox and I can't find a property called "format". I have Excel 2013 version, but I can't see it in the VBA property list ... am I missing something? sorry ..

Comment: Hmm, maybe numberformat? Let me check. (I was looking stuff up here anyway, struggling with debugging, hence the quick response time :) )

Comment: Wow, apparently you can't change the format of a textbox in Excel. What you can do is format the date appearing in it. This might however make dealing with it as a date later a bit difficult... Anyway, use this: `Format(DateAdd("m", 1, CDate(ADD_Inc_DATE_TXT.Value)), "dd/mm/yyyy")` Let me update my answer...

Comment: I have added "Additional Information" in my original post above which may be of help to see if I have got something wrong ...

Comment: When I enter in your code Format(DateAdd("m", 1, CDate(ADD_Inc_DATE_TXT.Value)), "dd/mm/yyyy") then it asks for a = etc each time I enter what it is looking for, something else pops up, I am entering the code on the next line under the original code you gave me.

Comment: Your updated code worked perfectly when I manually typed it, it had the correct date format. And this time when I used the date picker, it entered the date, but in the wrong format, but I believe the problem is not with your code, but the code of the calendar picker. Thank you so VERY much ... if you could help with the calendar date format I'd be grateful, if not I'll try & re-post it in a new question. Thank so much

Comment: Glad I could help. Please post it as a new question, it will be more useful for future googlers that way. Also, I will need a lot of info, like your code, the kind of date/time picked you are using etc. Easier in a new question.